# How to get html of element with arrow function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The syntax we are using requires the use of arrow functions. I'm still learning our software so I couldn't answer as to why. The issue is I do not know how to convert function() { }callbacks to (e) => callbacks and the solutions I have tried are not working.

I have read all the documentation and other answers regarding .each(), .find(), .html(), and $(this) vs $(e.currentTarget)

JsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/4gvowa18/2/

```
var i = 0;
var withThis = $(document).find("p").each(function(){
  $(this).html(i++);
  console.log($(this).html());
});

var j = 10;
var withArrow = $(document).find("p").each((e) =>{
    $(e.currentTarget).html(j++);
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).html());
});
```

`withThis` runs as expected but `withArrow` does not

Expected results: Both functions change the html of the

tags to the new content. When logging the html tag content both functions should print to the console.

Actual: Only the first function changes the contents of the

tag. The first function prints the correct values to the console but the second function prints undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the arrow function.

You are just using the [each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function the wrong way. You need to use the `value` to get the element. Normal function does not have this issue as you are using `this` and not the callback params.

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

**Corrected Snippet**

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

var i = 0;
$(document).find("p").each(function() {
  $(this).html(i++);
  //console.log($(this).html());
});

var j = 10;
$(document).find("p").each((i, e) => {
  $(e).html(j++);
  //console.log($(e).html());
});

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  banner.addClass("alt")
  withArrow();
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="banner-message">
  <p>TEST</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha. This seems like I am still just very new to the language. Thank you so much.  So .currentTarget is just for event handlers yes?

Comment: yes, but you don't need that as `each` is giving you the element.